# plot a performance envelope (changable ellipse)

Tags: plotting, charts, envelope

I am learning by myself to use Mathematica. I am quite new actually. I'd like to plot something that resembles the picture below, but here's the thing, I want to know if there is a possibility to creat a chart where I can add X and Y values, allowing it to plot the graphic but if I change the values, the graphic would change. I hope I make myself clear, English is not my first language. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. There are several Wolfram Demonstration projects on ellipses that might be close to what you are looking for. e.g. [this](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConicSectionCurves/).

Comment: What is the relationship between the ellipse and the X and Y values?

Comment: X is tension, larger values than Y; Y is differential pressure

Comment: Take a look at the help for `Manipulate`, which facilitates interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want, but the following creates an ellipse whose size and orientation can be controlled interactively

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[], 
   Ellipsoid[{0, 0}, 
    Transpose[
      RotationMatrix[θ]].DiagonalMatrix[{r^2, 
       R^2}].RotationMatrix[θ]]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Axes -> True, 
  GridLines -> Automatic], {r, 1, 2}, {R, 1, 2}, {θ, 0, π}]
```